# Microstep driver with arduino to control DC motor

Tags: dc-motor, arduino-uno, microstepping

I am new to robotics and I am learning and understanding basic circuits. I am using two microstep drivers with a single Arduino to control the speed and direction of two stepper motors. Can I use microstep driver to control the speed and direction of a DC motor with an Arduino?
As I am new to robotics, a detailed explanation will help me a lot.

Comment: try it ... see what happens